# Partition of number's squares

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

The problem is to divide $\{k^2\}_{k=1}^{1000}$ into two groups of 500 numbers each, such that they have equal sum.

I know that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6},
$$
but it isn't enough for me to solve this. Please help me, if you can.

Comment: Why do you think this is necessarily possible?

Comment: The first $n$ I can see this is possible for is $n=8$, and the greedy algorithm from the largest number produces the partitioning. Not sure this will or will  not work for $n=1000$

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align}
n^2+(n+3)^2&=2n^2+6n+9\;,\\
(n+1)^2+(n+2)^2&=2n^2+6n+5\;.
\end{align}

So group the numbers in groups of $8$ and assign them $abbabaab$ in each group.